# What is the minimum requirement on $f$ such that $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-st)f(t)dt = \int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is the minimum requirement on $f$ such that $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-st)f(t)dt = \int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt$?

I think if I take $f$ to be measurable and $f\in L^1(0, \infty)$, then by dominated convergence theorem we get that. Or is there any weaker condition? or is reasoning correct?

Comment: What about polynomials? or Holder space $C^{k,\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: yes, for continuous function also hold.

Comment: the minimum requirement is that $\lim_{s\to 0}\int e^{-xt}f(t)\,\mathrm d t=\int \lim_{s\to 0}e^{-xt}f(t)\,\mathrm d t$

Comment: Though comical, @Masacroso has an important point. It is possible that there is no necessary and sufficient condition more elegantly stated than the original property. Moreover, it could be (and generically is likely) the case that the set of sufficient conditions is not linearly ordered by strength. There may be many minimal requirements! This shouldn't discourage you from searching from a minimum requirement, however. It may exist and be very enlightening to discover.

Comment: Note this is the  integral analogue of Abel Summation, which agrees with Cesaro Summation wherever the latter is defined (which itself agrees with standard summation whenever the sum classically converges). Up to, perhaps, some technical details, I would expect a very similar result for integrals.

Answer (score 2):

If  $$F(0)=\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T f(t)dt$$ converges then $$ F(s) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T f(t)e^{-st}dt=\int_0^\infty (\int_0^T f(t)dt) s e^{-sT}dT$$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$ and 
$$\frac{F(s)}{s} = \int_0^\infty (F(0)+o(1)) e^{-sT}dT= \frac{F(0)}{s}+o(\frac{1}{\Re(s)})$$
Thus for $r\in [0,\pi/2)$
$$\lim_{s \to 0, arg(s) \in (-r,r)} F(s) =F(0)$$
This is the [Abelian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) for Laplace transforms.